# Product search on Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I am developing a product website on Orchard CMS. The products are set up as content items. I would like to develop a simple product search widget on the homepage with price and types as search criteria.  Do I have to develop a custom widget for this? How do perform a filtering on content items and show as search results? Can I use projector for this?  Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Search, Indexing, and Lucene modules provide a simple search out of the box, including search on custom properties. You can see how that works in the [Orchard Search Documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Search-and-indexing).

To add filtering criteria on particular properties I think you'd need to write your own version of the Search module. I'd look at the module's source code to see how it works and see if it could be extended.